# String(data: x, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) equivalent in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

In earlier versions of Swift I could convert `NSData` to a UTF8 string thus:

```
let desc:String = String(data: requestData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

(The documentation for `NSString`'s `init(data:NSData,encoding:NSStringEncoding)` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416374-init).)

In Swift 3 using `Data` I would expect something like

```
let desc:String = requestData.description(usedEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

But that does not exist (`Data`'s documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data)). What is the correct Swift 3 translation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's actually the same syntax

> `init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)`

---

```
let desc = String(data: requestData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The annotations are not for the compiler they are for me, I'm not yet on top of Swift and I find it useful to have the type of my variables staring me in the face. It also highlights quickly when I am returned an unexpected type.

Comment: But you can make it worse especially when dealing with optionals.

Comment: For example when you annotate an optional which is a non-optional in practice. You can see that often in questions here on SO. In this case the compiler trusts you and does not complain.